# cannot find name 'mapStateToProps' . [2304]

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm attempting to migrate my react-native project to typescript, and just moving module by module trying to solve all error messages, but I can't seem to understand what this one means: "cannot find name 'mapStateToProps'. I suspect it has to do with the @type/react-redux library, but I can't be sure.

```
mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        playing: state.toggle.playing,
        activeFile: state.activeFile,
        title: state.activeFile && state.units.files[state.activeFile].title
    };
};
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply because you forgot the `const` (or `let`) keyword before mapStateToProps that you are warned that you are trying to reference something that doesn't exist.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ...
```